# Learn Python the hard way — exercise 15 error while running file again

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am trying to run this code

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print(f"Here's your file {filename}:")
print(txt.read())

print("Type the filename again:")
file_again = input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print(txt_again.read())
```

This code asks me to enter the file name again but when I enter it, it gives me error. Attached is the error image.  Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong?

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAp0l.jpg)

Comment: Does the file ex15_sample.txt exist in the same directory for sure?

Comment: I would recommend you to not use white characters in file and directory names

Comment: As Windmill said, the file is in different directory. Try giving the full path instead of filename second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python takes file name from current directory of user, not script. So, if you're launching your script from `C:/Users/prince.bhatia`, it actually looks for a file `C:/Users/prince.bhatia/ex15_sample.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the code from the next directory.
Goto Powershell Prompt and change the directory to the directory where you have kept your files.and run your script.

Or read this document for absolute path specification:

https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/